# how to loop through arguments in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

I would like to write a bash script with unknown amount of arguments.

How can I walk through these arguments and do something with them?

A wrong attempt would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $args; do 
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's a special syntax for this:

```
for i do
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

More generally, the list of parameters of the current script or function is available through the special variable `$@`.

```
for i in "$@"; do
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

Note that you need the double quotes around `$@`, otherwise the parameters undergo wildcard expansion and field splitting. `"$@"` is magic: despite the double quotes, it expands into as many fields as there are parameters.

```
print_arguments () {
  for i in "$@"; do printf '%s\n' "$i"; done
}
print_arguments 'hello world' '*' 'special  !\characters' '-n' # prints 4 lines
print_arguments ''                                             # prints one empty line
print_arguments                                                # prints nothing
```

Answer (score 6):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
for f in "$@"; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

You should quote `$@` because it is possible for arguments to contain spaces (or newlines, etc.) if you quote them, or escape them with a `\`. For example:

```
./myscript one 'two three'
```

That's two arguments rather than three, due to the quotes. If you don't quote `$@`, those arguments will be broken up within the script.

Comment: There's a shorthand for this `for f; do ...`