# Shell function that consumes two arguments per loop iteration

Tags: shell, arguments

I'm writing some iptables scripts, and I want to write a function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters and consumes them two at a time. Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Allow inbound sessions for a specific service
iptables --append INPUT --protocol $PROTO --destination-port $PORT \
   --match state --state NEW --jump ACCEPT || exit 1
```

I found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79343/how-to-loop-through-arguments-in-a-bash-script#79353) that shows the right syntax for looping through an arbitrary number of arguments, but I don't know how to grab two arguments in each iteration. How do I get both `$PROTO` and `$PORT` from the caller (from `$@`, two args at a time)?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Where do `$PROTO` and `$PORT` come from? Where's your arbitrary number of parameters? What is an example of how you'd like this script to be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
while [ "$#" -ge 2 ]; do
  proto=$1 port=$2
  shift 2
  iptables --append INPUT --protocol "$proto" --destination-port "$port" \
    --match state --state NEW --jump ACCEPT || exit 1
done
```

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
for proto port do
  iptables --append INPUT --protocol "$proto" --destination-port "$port" \
    --match state --state NEW --jump ACCEPT || exit 1
done
```

One difference is that if there's an odd number of argument, there will be an extra run with `$proto` containing the last argument and `$port` being set but empty (as if we had used `[ "$#" -gt 0 ]` instead of `[ "$#" -ge 2 ]` in the previous example).